# Group elements from an array with a new element containing group value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have an array like this one:

```
$array = [
     ['Categoria' => 'example', 'Servico' => 'name1'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example', 'Servico' => 'name2'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example', 'Servico' => 'name3'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example2', 'Servico' => 'name4'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example2', 'Servico' => 'name5'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example2', 'Servico' => 'name6'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example3', 'Servico' => 'name7'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example3', 'Servico' => 'name8'],
     ['Categoria' => 'example3', 'Servico' => 'name9']
];
```

I need to transform this on something like:

```
[
    [
        'Servico' => 'example',
        'children' => [
            ['Servico' => 'name1'],
            ['Servico' => 'name2'],
            ['Servico' => 'name3'],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'Servico' => 'example2',
        'children' => [
            ['Servico' => 'name4'],
            ['Servico' => 'name5'],
            ['Servico' => 'name6'],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'Servico' => 'example3',
        'children' => [
            ['Servico' => 'name7'],
            ['Servico' => 'name8'],
            ['Servico' => 'name9'],
        ]
    ],
]
```

I have read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113256/group-array-values-based-on-key-in-php) and I successfully have grouped my array, but I couldn't find a way to format the array in a way I have `Servico` and `children` on each object.

Someone have any ideas?

Comment: Wait... How can you have several keys in the same array with the same name?

Comment: @Andreas, I have a `faher` with **Servico** and all of its `children` also must have **Servico** as a key. I don't think this would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for multiple loops or conditions or counters here.

Every group's `Servico` value (`$row['Categoria']`) can be safely overwritten on each iteration.

Each new `$row['Servico']` value is to be unconditionally pushed into the respective `children` subarray.

After using `$row['Categoria']` to provide temporary grouping keys in the result array, re-index the result with `array_values()`.

*Note: I am electing to flatten the data structure of `children` to be an indexed array.  I don't see any value in creating single-element associative arrays for each entry.  If you DO want that then push `['Servico' => $row['Servico']]` into the `children`.

Functional-style with `array_reduce()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/csppI))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $array,
            function ($carry, $row) {
                $carry[$row['Categoria']]['Servico'] = $row['Categoria'];
                $carry[$row['Categoria']]['children'][] = $row['Servico'];
                return $carry;
            }
        )
    )
);
```

---

Classic `foreach()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9PCqW))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['Categoria']]['Servico'] = $row['Categoria'];
    $result[$row['Categoria']]['children'][] = $row['Servico'];
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Comment: this one is perfect! But I was playing with your code and I did something like [that](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fc206640c2b79bcefaee606e7e56c7cfedda711), the only issue is that the index of each array is the name of the `Servico`, instead of a number, like your example. Do you know what could I change to reach your result with only one for?

Comment: No.  Unfortunately you are not going to be able to employ php's automated array indexing on two levels within one foreach loop.  I am sure the process can be done in one loop, but you would lose the auto-indexing (you would have to use counters and increment them conditionally -- created convoluted code).  I recommend two loops in this case.

Comment: That's what I thought. I will use two loops then. Thank you very much for your answer. Problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can foreach the array and build a new array with the structure you want.

```
$new =array();
Foreach($A as $item){
    If(!isset($new[$item['Categoria']])) $new[$item['Categoria']] = array(); // create array of not set
    $new[$item['Categoria']][] = $item['Servico']; // add servico item to array
}
```

This loops each item if it does not find the subarray it will create it.
Then add the 'name' values in the subarray.

> Edit, see now that you want your output array to be named B, just change 'new' to 'B' in the code.

Comment: this works, but it doesn't put the name of the keys on each object, such as `Servico` and `children`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

just assume $array is your array

```
$i=0;
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $arr)
{
    if($i !=0 && $arr['Categoria'] == $temp[$i-1]['Servico']){
        $temp[$i-1]['children']['Servico'] = $arr['Servico'];
    }else{
        $temp[$i]['Servico'] =$arr['Categoria'];
        $temp[$i]['children']['Servico'] = $arr['Servico'];
        $i++;
    }
}
//$temp is your new array
```

Comment: This method doesn't read the whole array. It returned to me only one child for each element.