# Group array items by key value adding an associative element with the grouped values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

Having the following array:

```
$a = [
    "category" => "Music", 
    "items" => [
        ["ID" => "1", "start_date" => "2018-11-20", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"],
        ["ID" => "2", "start_date" => "2018-11-22", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"],
        ["ID" => "3", "start_date" => "2018-11-26", "end_date" => "2018-11-30"],
        ["ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-27", "end_date" => "2018-11-31"],
        ["ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-29", "end_date" => "2018-11-31"]
    ]
];
```

I would like to 'group' the arrays by `end_date` **but not** using `end_date` as key as I saw in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113256/group-array-values-based-on-key-in-php) or [forums](https://github.com/jakezatecky/array_group_by/blob/master/src/array_group_by.php), but by adding the value of `end_date` as a value of a new key.

So that the expected result would be:

```
array(
    "category" => "Music",
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "date" => "2018-11-28",
            array("ID" => "1", "start_date" => "2018-11-20", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"),
            array("ID" => "2", "start_date" => "2018-11-22", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"),
        ),
        array(
            "date" => "2018-11-30",
            array("ID" => "3", "start_date" => "2018-11-26", "end_date" => "2018-11-30")
        ),
        array(
            "date" => "2018-11-31",
            array("ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-27", "end_date" => "2018-11-31"),
            array("ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-29", "end_date" => "2018-11-31")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you should include an attempt.

Comment: What don't you want to use the date as a key?

Comment: @Andreas: I did linked my attempts (see link to 'forum' and 'posts').

Comment: @Omari: because I'm trying to build an API that outputs a JSON which shall be used by a APP that draws it's content associating keys and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the array and build an temporary associative array with the end date as the key.
Then copy the original array and unset the 'items' and add the new temporary array values.

```
$a = array("category" => "Music", 
        "items" => array(
            array("ID" => "1", "start_date" => "2018-11-20", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"),
            array("ID" => "2", "start_date" => "2018-11-22", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"),
            array("ID" => "3", "start_date" => "2018-11-26", "end_date" => "2018-11-30"),
            array("ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-27", "end_date" => "2018-11-31"),
            array("ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-29", "end_date" => "2018-11-31")
        )
);

foreach($a['items'] as $item){
    $new[$item['end_date']]['date'] = $item['end_date'];
    $new[$item['end_date']][] = $item;
}
$res = $a;
unset($res['items']);
$res['items'] = array_values($new);


var_dump($res);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["category"]=>
  string(5) "Music"
  ["items"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-11-28"
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["start_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-20"
        ["end_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-28"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["start_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-22"
        ["end_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-28"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-11-30"
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["start_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-26"
        ["end_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-30"
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-11-31"
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["start_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-27"
        ["end_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-31"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["start_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-29"
        ["end_date"]=>
        string(10) "2018-11-31"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/foKL7

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional-style programming to group and re-index the `items` subarray without declaring any temporary variables in the global space.

As you iterate each row of `$array['items']`, use temporary keys for grouping and push rows into their respective group.  When finished grouping, re-index the data with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QZSQE))

```
$array = [
    "category" => "Music", 
    "items" => [
        ["ID" => "1", "start_date" => "2018-11-20", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"],
        ["ID" => "2", "start_date" => "2018-11-22", "end_date" => "2018-11-28"],
        ["ID" => "3", "start_date" => "2018-11-26", "end_date" => "2018-11-30"],
        ["ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-27", "end_date" => "2018-11-31"],
        ["ID" => "4", "start_date" => "2018-11-29", "end_date" => "2018-11-31"]
    ]
];

$array["items"] = array_values(
    array_reduce(
        $array["items"],
        function ($carry, $row) {
            $carry[$row["end_date"]]["data"] = $row["end_date"];
            $carry[$row["end_date"]][] = $row;
            return $carry;
        }
    )
);
var_export($array);
```