# Group array values based on key and count quantity of grouped products in php

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Maybe someone has already asked, but I didn't find the right answer. I need group arrays by `mpn` and `product_id` key  values and count it's quantities.
my array:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => Product HTC
            [mpn] => 
            [quantity] => 3
            [product_id] => 28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => Product HTC
            [mpn] => ggg
            [quantity] => 5
            [product_id] => 28
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => Product HTC
            [mpn] => ggg
            [quantity] => 1
            [product_id] => 28
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product] => Product HTC
            [mpn] => ggg
            [quantity] => 1
            [product_id] => 28
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product] => Product HTC
            [mpn] => fff
            [quantity] => 1
            [product_id] => 28
        )
```

the desired result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [product] => Product HTC
        [mpn] => 
        [quantity] => 3
        [product_id] => 28
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product] => Product HTC
        [mpn] => ggg
        [quantity] => 7
        [product_id] => 28
    )


[2] => Array
    (
        [product] => Product HTC
        [mpn] => fff
        [quantity] => 1
        [product_id] => 28
    )
```

I have tried this suggestion [Group array values based on key in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113256/group-array-values-based-on-key-in-php) but no success.

Comment: _"I have tried this suggestion [...] but no success."_ - please _show us_ what you tried then, and give a _proper_ problem description along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you can obtain an array group by mpn. With **$myList** is your original array.

```
// For Each Element
foreach ($myList as $myKey => $myValue)
{
    // Define New Key
    $newKey = $myValue["mpn"];

    // You can Define New Key with Concatenation of Multiple Element
    // Ex : $newKey = $myValue["mpn"]."_".$myValue["product_id"];

    // If Never Memorised OR Already Memorised
    if(!array_key_exists($newKey,$newList)) $newList["$newKey"] = $myValue;
    else $newList["$newKey"]["quantity"] = bcadd($newList["$newKey"]["quantity"],$myValue["quantity"],0);
}
// End - For Each Element

// Display Result
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newList); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example using a simple loop.

```
<?php
function group_by_mpn($array){
    $mpn = array();
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(!in_array($value['mpn'], $mpn)){
            $mpn[] = $value['mpn'];
            $result[] = $value;
        }else{
            $index = array_search($value['mpn'], $mpn);
            $result[$index]['quantity'] = $result[$index]['quantity'] + $value['quantity'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$array = array(
    array('product' => 'Product HTC', 'mpn' => '', 'quantity' => 3, 'product_id' => 28),
    array('product' => 'Product HTC', 'mpn' => 'ggg', 'quantity' => 5, 'product_id' => 28),
    array('product' => 'Product HTC', 'mpn' => 'ggg', 'quantity' => 1, 'product_id' => 28),
    array('product' => 'Product HTC', 'mpn' => 'ggg', 'quantity' => 1, 'product_id' => 28),
    array('product' => 'Product HTC', 'mpn' => 'fff', 'quantity' => 1, 'product_id' => 28),
);

$result = group_by_mpn($array);
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Your solution may be a bit too complex. But I upvoted because it inspired me to construct my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @Juan, looking at my answer a day later it seems that I already don't understand how it works so indeed it may be a little too complex :)